Get specific Helm chart release from git
Dumb question time.
I want to pull an older release of the aws-ebs-csi-driver from git.
The command below pulls the latest version -v1.30.0 but I would like to use v1.20.0
helm repo add aws-ebs-csi-driver https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-ebs-csi-driver
helm repo update


You can use helm search repo command to find older versions of Helm chart:
$ helm search repo aws-ebs-csi-driver/aws-ebs-csi-driver -l
NAME                                    CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION
aws-ebs-csi-driver/aws-ebs-csi-driver   2.30.0          1.30.0      A Helm chart for AWS EBS CSI Driver
aws-ebs-csi-driver/aws-ebs-csi-driver   2.29.1          1.29.1      A Helm chart for AWS EBS CSI Driver
aws-ebs-csi-driver/aws-ebs-csi-driver   2.29.0          1.29.0      A Helm chart for AWS EBS CSI Driver
...
aws-ebs-csi-driver/aws-ebs-csi-driver   2.22.0          1.22.0      A Helm chart for AWS EBS CSI Driver
aws-ebs-csi-driver/aws-ebs-csi-driver   2.21.0          1.21.0      A Helm chart for AWS EBS CSI Driver
aws-ebs-csi-driver/aws-ebs-csi-driver   2.20.0          1.20.0      A Helm chart for AWS EBS CSI Driver
aws-ebs-csi-driver/aws-ebs-csi-driver   2.19.0          1.19.0      A Helm chart for AWS EBS CSI Driver
...

As you can see chart version 2.20.0 installs aws-ebs-csi-driver version 1.20.0. You can install the chart with:
helm install aws-ebs-csi-driver aws-ebs-csi-driver/aws-ebs-csi-driver --version 2.20.0


Nice one, thanks Vasilii!
